# How can I show realtime text analysis of a Django form Textarea (models.TextField)?

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms

OK, so I have a model class `Recipe` and a form class `AddRecipeForm` that is based on `Recipe` (`via forms.ModelForm`).

The form shows up in my html template and works, but I want to implement a special type of form validation. Basically, I want to do some text processing on some big text input fields as a user types his / her ingredients / directions.

I have code that figures out where all the amounts (numbers) in the ingredient text are, and identifies and classifies all the units (e.g. 'lbs.', 'gr', etc...). --> I'd love to be able to basically have a text-box right by the side of the form in `add_recipe.html` that performs this text processing (via highlighting, bold, etc) in real time.

However, I'm really not sure how to do it. I've been reading about doing real-time form validation via `AJAX`, `jquery`, 'django channels', or maybe just `django`'s `ModelForm.clean()` method, but I'm not sure which would be best or where to start. Any pointers / suggestions would be awesome!

Here's my (simplified) code:

### models.py

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    ingredients_text = models.TextField(max_length=2048*2)
    instructions_text = models.TextField(max_length=2048*4)
```

### forms.py

```
class AddRecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = '__all__'
```

### views.py

```
def add_recipe(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        add_recipe_form = AddRecipeForm(request.POST)
        if add_recipe_form.is_valid():
            recipe = add_recipe_form.save()
            recipe.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/recipes/detail/{}/'.format(recipe.id))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid values :( Try again?')
    else:
        add_recipe_form = AddRecipeForm()

    context = {
        'add_recipe_form': add_recipe_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'home/add_recipe.html', context)
```

### home/templates/home/add_recipe.py (html template)

sidenote: I'm using the [materialize](http://materializecss.com/) framework, so I'm doing forms with a little helper so the CSS doesn't conflict with django - I can stop using it if need be though...

```
{% extends "home/index.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load materialize %}
    <h2> Add a Recipe </h2>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <p>{{add_recipe_form.ingredients_text|as_material:"s12 m6"}}</p>
        <div class="col s12 m6 textbox">  TODO (realtime validation textbox)  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>{{add_recipe_form.instructions_text|as_material:"s12 m6"}}</p>
        <div class="col s12 m6 textbox"> TODO (realtime validation textbox) </div>
    </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: That can all be handled client-side with Javascript, there's really no need for channels or using the forms clean method. It's hard to say exactly what you should do, but the general idea would be to add an event listener on the text input that you want to monitor. Check out the available input events that you can use: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp

Comment: Do you want filter the result from the field? What do you mean  text processing?

Comment: @Aison by text processing, I mean e.g. finding all numbers, transforming number phrases into numeric ('two' --> 2), and identifying and cleaning up amounts (e.g. 'T.' --> 'tbsp.'). Also cleaning up any whitespace issues, formatting, etc.

Example:
2 and a half egg yolks, whisked --> '2 1/2 egg yolks, whisked' where '2 1/2' is highlighted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get Django's Form class involved and don't worry about django-channels. You just need to setup a simple API that takes a JSON of whatever is in your text field and returns a result of processed text. JavaScript would be responsible for calling the API via AJAX and doing something with the response.

It's not 100% clear what you're doing with the processed text but if you're replacing the words "two and a half" with "2 1/2", I could see the server responding with a key value pair of {"two and a half": "2 1/2"} and allowing JavaScript to find and replace that text.